# GROUP_CONCAT dentro de otro GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: mysql

Tengo una consulta que me da una columna con los siguientes resultados:

```
0,1,1,1,1
1,1
0,1,1,0,1,1
0,1,1
```

Necesito que si la cadena contiene sólo unos, me devuelva a, si tiene sólo 0,1,1 o cadenas de 0,1,1 me devuelva b y sino me devuelva c

El resultado debería ser:

```
c
a
b
b
```

La consulta funciona hasta que intento poner el GROUP_CONCAT dentro del GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT)

```
SELECT
t1.id,
(
  SELECT
  CASE
  WHEN GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t3.type) = '1' THEN 'a'
  WHEN GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(t3.type), '0,1,1', '2')) = '2' THEN 'b'
  ELSE 'c'
  END
  FROM table2 t2
  LEFT JOIN table3 t3 ON (t3.id_test = t2.id_test)
  WHERE t2.another_id = t1.another_id
) as value1
FROM table1 t1
```

Para el caso de la tercera fila, si cambio el REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT()) por su resultado "2,2" no aparece el error, pero con ello puesto me devuelve lo siguiente:

```
[Err] 1111 - Invalid use of group function
```

Muchas gracias

Comment: Estás diciendo que si tiene solo unos ( "1" )  te devuelva "a" y tu en el resultado esperado colocaste en el segundo resultado "b"... estoy interpretando mal? o tu definiste mal la pregunta?

Comment: Perdón, sí, me había equivocado, unos equivale a "a". Ya he editado la pregunta

Comment: Me da la impresión de que esto se podría resolver mejor planteando la consulta de otro modo. Habría que ver un ejemplo de los datos , además ¿no le falta un `GROUP BY` a esa consulta?. Y, ¿si por casualidad agrupara los 1 y los 0 en un orden distinto? Yo no veo ningún orden ni control en los `GROUP_CONCAT` y por tanto una misma consulta podría en unos casos darte una letra, en otros otra, a capricho del manejador.

Comment: @A.Cedano Los 1 y los 0 van asociados a unas ids y siempre aparecen en el mismo orden, eso está controlado. El `GROUP BY` no veo que me sea necesario.